# How to select the previous column of a table based on the text of the next column using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, dom, html-table

I am trying to select the previous column of a webtable based on the text of the next column. Here is my code:

```
for(WebElement eachrow:noofrows)
{
     List<WebElement> col3=eachrow.findElements(By.xpath("//td[3]")); 

     for(WebElement text:col3)  
     {
        String s1=text.getText();
        System.out.println(s1);
        if(s1==opt1)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]")).click();
        }
     }

     if(t.equals(choice1)||t.equals(choice2))
     {
        text.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]")).click();
     }
```

[image: Here is a copy of the dom]

Here is the html:

style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; -moz-user-select: none;">

```
<div class="ib10_checklist_question">An angel investor is the best choice. Why? Select up to two reasons. This is the appropriate funding amount for an angel investor. Angel investors are the best choice for backing an idea to get off the ground. Angel investors are backed by churches. Angel investors have limitless funds. </div>
<div class="ib10_checklist_bg">




<table style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:10%">
<td style="width:5%"/>
<td style="width:5%">
  <div class="ibg_checkbox" onclick="if (c2_callFunction) c2_callFunction('lvl2_check',[0]);">b</div>
</td>
<td class="ib10_checklist_text" style="width:100%">This is the appropriate funding amount for an angel investor.</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Add `html` code to your question as text, not as attached image! Also clarify which is the target element and specify errors if any occurs. Thx

Comment: Depending on the text of the <td class="ib10_checklist_text----> I want to select <div class="ibg_checkbox"---->    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Xpath By using the text of `<td class="ib10_checklist_text---->`

```
//*[text()='This is the appropriate funding amount for an angel investor.']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/div
```

Xpath By Using the class value of `<td class="ib10_checklist_text---->`

```
 //td[@class='ib10_checklist_text']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/div
```

If you want to explore it more then this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67bzMdbhIuw) will be useful for you.

Comment: please vote and accept the answer to maintain the hygiene :) Thanks!